# Apply to style to parent on hover child and if parent is enabled

Tags: less

I have this part of html code:

```
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="filter[theme_tag_ids_mi][60]" value="Développement culturel">
                                                                    Développement culturel (16)</label>
```

This the less style:

```
 input[type=checkbox]:enabled {
      cursor: pointer;
      & {
          color: #007884;
          cursor: pointer;
      }
  }
```

The idea is to apply color and cursor on enabled input (the parent) if the user hover the label (child).

Mnfortunately my less code didn't work

Comment: Hmm, as far as I remember in CSS you can't change parent element properties depending on its child element state (i.e. it's a CSS limitation thus no preprocessor can help). Note that `&` only represents parent selector identifier (i.e. just an alias/shorcut used to build/compose some other selector) - it's not for modifying parent element rules itself (yet again this is just not possible in CSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
& input[type=checkbox]:checked {
       color: #007884;
          cursor: pointer;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/hasuwumuxe/edit?html,css

Comment: maybe the flag is "checked " and not "enabled"

Comment: I tried like this & { without even mention enabled or checked